# Python - integers as input piped to subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

I have a list containing integers and want to direct it to a shell command that creates a histogram from it (see [here](https://github.com/bitly/data_hacks/blob/master/data_hacks/histogram.py)).

For now, let's mimick the histogram generating script by a simple shell script `echo_script.sh` that echoes all the input:

```
#/bin/sh
echo $@
```

From within Python, I'd like to direct the contents of a list to that command. I suppose it involves some fiddling with `subprocess`.

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
# subprocess stuff, writing numbers to stdin of echo_script.sh process?
```

I'd like to have the following output to stdout:

```
1 2 3
```

Note that I'm aware of solutions that involve storing the list contents in a temporary file and piping that file to `echo_script.sh`. I'd like to avoid that.

EDIT: The histogram.py script that I'm working with does not support reading in an arbitrary number of appended arguments, like `echo 1 2 3` would do. It only reads from `stdin`. Hence, the example above is misleading. An approach I have tried:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["wc", "-l"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write(bytes([42]))
```

This outputs 1 which is the correct line count but actually the number of bytes written. So I have two more questions:

- How can I correctly use an array of bytes to send to `proc.stdin.write`?
- How can I redirect stdout of proc to the current process?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import subprocess

path_to_script = "./echo_script.sh"
numbers = [1, 2 ,3]
numbers_str = ' '.join(str(i) for i in numbers) # should give you '1 2 3'

subprocess.call([path_to_script, numbers_str])
```

Edit to your edit:

I think you may need to use subprocess.Popen then. This may work:

```
import subprocess

script = "/path/to/script.py"

numbers = [1, 2 ,3]
numbers_str = ' '.join(str(i) for i in numbers) + '\n' # should give you '1 2 3'

proc = subprocess.Popen(script, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write(numbers_str)
proc.stdin.close()
print(proc.stdout.read())
```

Comment: This approach is useful for the `echo` example. However, it works not with the given script. I have edited my question. Thanks for your help! I'd be happy if you had another look.

Comment: Your edit put me on the right track, thanks! I applied some modifications: I joined the numbers using the newline character. `proc.std.write()` requires a byte object, so I convert `numbers_str` via `bytearray(numbers_str, 'utf-8')`. Same goes for the output of `read`, so I put a `.decode()`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

```
import subprocess
l = [1, 2, 3]
l = ' '.join(str(x) for x in l)
subprocess.call(["./echo_script.sh {}".format(l)], shell=True)
```

Comment: If its a number per line then changing `' '.join(str(x) for x in l)` to `'\n'.join(str(x) for x in l)` should work.

Comment: This approach is useful for the echo example. However, it works not with the given script. I have edited my question, sorry about the misunderstanding. Thanks for your help! I'd be happy if you had another look.